# PyCharm No module named 'nltk' even though I've installed it using pip3?

Tags: python, pycharm, nltk

```
import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'
```

This is the error that I get from running PyCharm 2021.3.2 (Community Edition).

However, when I go to my terminal and try
`pip3 install nltk`

I see that

```
Requirement already satisfied: nltk in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: click in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from nltk) (8.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: regex>=2021.8.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from nltk) (2022.9.13)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from nltk) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from nltk) (4.64.1)
```

So it seems that I've already installed `nltk`? But why is PyCharm still giving me that error? I'm using macOS Monterey 12.6 if that helps with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to try:

- On your terminal, check which on which python environment you're using your script. It's a common source of headaches that using python 2.7 and python 3.x would not work for packages only installed with either pip or pip3. On the terminal do

```
python --version
```

and (if available)

```
python3 --version
```

And check if you can make it work after installing the same package with `pip` (as opposed to `pip3`).

- using conda as a package manager can lead to millions of conflicts across your system. Are you by any chance using conda/anaconda? If so, you should try intalling the package with `conda` instead of `pip`.
- check that whatever python you're using, it can reach the location of wherever you installled PyCharm.
- Check if your package was installed locally as opposed as globally. For the former, do `pip list` on your terminal. For the latter, do `pip list --user` instead.

Comment: Protip:  On Apple Silcon Mac's its best to use pyenv with the virtualenv plugin for pyenv.